# How to have global parameters in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing an application in cakephp 3.

I want to have global variables that can be read from everywhere, even in layouts and views.

how can I save these parameters?

Comment: write this into core.php like `Configure::write('test',true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write configuration like this in your `core.php` :

```
Configure::write('Company', [
   'name' => 'Pizza, Inc.',
   'slogan' => 'Pizza for your body and soul'
]);
```

and when you can read it like this:

```
Configure::read('Company.name');
Configure::read('Company.slogan');
Configure::read('Company');
```

if you don't like to write new parameters in `core.php`. you can write it in another file and load it into core.php.
further tutorials are in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html

Comment: Above is not for cakephp 3.x.